# how do i check for specific element value before reading this xml - django python

Tags: python, xml, django

I am reading elements from xml and saving them into db. Before I read the part of xml which i am going to save into db, i want to check if that part is relevant to my case. more exactly, i will check if `<Country>GERMANY</Country>` is there. only then i will read this part and save into db.

this is example xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
 <info>
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <Country>SWEDEN</Country>        
 </info>
 <info>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <Country>GERMANY</Country>        
 </info>
</data>
```

how do i do this in python? this is the start of my code

```
datei = ET.parse(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\\table.xml')
datas = datei.getroot()        
for info in data:
   #here i need to check if Country=="GERMANY"
```

what is the best way to check first if elements has the wanted value and then go inside?

Comment: which XML library are you using?

Comment: @YuvalAdam, i am using this: ``import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET``

Comment: `any(country.text == 'GERMANY' for country in root.iterfind('.//info/Country'))`

Comment: @falsetru, what does it return?

Comment: It will evaluate to `True` only if there is any `Country` tag with `GERMANY` as its text.

Comment: @falsetru, ok very nice. thanks in tons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datei = ET.parse(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\\table.xml')
datas = datei.getroot()

for info in datas.findall('info'):
    if info.find('Country').text == 'GERMANY':
        # do whatever
        pass
```

For more advanced stuff just read the docs at http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: `iterfind('info')` better than `findall` especially if the file gets big.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know that the file contains `<Country>GERMANY</Country>`, a shorter version is:

```
if any(i.find('Country').text == 'GERMANY' for i in datas.iterfind('info')):
   print('Found It!')
```